# exception exit failed with c++ call python script

Tags: c++, python

When my exe exiting after python script finish,I got a error point to **crt0dat.c**
[image]
The call stack like this...
[image]
Are there some error in my c++ code or in the python code?

the c++ code like this:

```
void PythonCall::call(std::vector<double>& s,std::vector<double>& b,std::vector<double>& t,std::vector<double>& y)
{

    PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyObject* tPyList = convert2PythonList(t);
    PyObject* yPyList = convert2PythonList(y);
    PyTuple_SetItem(args,0,tPyList);
    PyTuple_SetItem(args,1,yPyList);

    PyObject* r = PyObject_CallObject(func,args);

    PyObject* item;


    PyObject* iter = PyObject_GetIter(r);
    /*{
    PyObject *errtype, *errvalue, *traceback;
    PyErr_Fetch(&errtype, &errvalue, &traceback);
    PyObject *s = PyObject_Str(errvalue);
    char *errstr = PyString_AsString(s);
    std::cout << "Python Error: " << errstr; 
    }*/


    item = PyIter_Next(iter);
    int i = 0;
    PyObject* iter2 = PyObject_GetIter(item);
    PyObject* item2;
    while (item2 = PyIter_Next(iter2))
    {
        s[i] = PyFloat_AsDouble(item2);
        Py_XDECREF(item2);
        i++;
    }
    Py_XDECREF(item);
    //Py_XDECREF(iter2);

    item = PyIter_Next(iter);
    i = 0;
    iter2 = PyObject_GetIter(item);
    while (item2 = PyIter_Next(iter2))
    {
        b[i] = PyFloat_AsDouble(item2);
        Py_XDECREF(item2);
        i++;
    }
    Py_XDECREF(item);
    //Py_XDECREF(iter2);

    //Py_XDECREF(iter);
    Py_XDECREF(args);
    Py_XDECREF(r);
    Py_XDECREF(item);
    Py_XDECREF(tPyList);
    Py_XDECREF(yPyList);
    //std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

and the python code:

```
def get_slope_baseLine(tl,xl):
    slopes = get_slope2(tl,xl)
    baselines = get_leakTime(tl,slopes)
    return slopes,baselines
```

sorry about my poor English...

Comment: Can you post any code? It's hard to debug code that is invisible.

Comment: How do you expect us to know that if you're not giving us your C++, nor your python code?

Comment: `doexit()` is likely being called because the program has terminated due to an access violation or some other termination condition.  What that is, depends entirely on what either the C++ or Python code is doing.  I second the first two comments - there's no way to know what is happening just by looking at the fact that the program terminated.

Comment: yes ,without any error it does not occur

Comment: Hello @wtm, welcome to StackOverflow. :)  Hope you're not turned off by the downvotes and flippant responses, but although you may feel you've provided a good screenshot that indicates the problem...we'd really need a lot more to figure out what's going on.  You can edit your question with the "edit" button to add more information about the context and code, without which we can't help you.  If you're new to seeking help on the internet, many people share this link as a good way of "helping us help you" http://sscce.org/

Comment: I was just try to add the code,it takes a lot of time...always got the   “add some context to explain the code sections”

Comment: well...What I want to know is in which file...the cpp or py.

Comment: @wtm One of the key questions is "what have you tried?"  For instance, what if the C++ code was very short and just returned some fixed values?  Does the crash still occur?  When you cut a piece of code out and it seems okay, then that directs your attention that the crash probably comes from the part you cut out.  :)  Try writing trivial "placeholder" routines that are easy to check.  Again, read that link I provided: http://sscce.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you're intending to iterate over two lists and decrement the ref counts of their elements, but you forget to reset `iter` so you're not iterating over the second list.

```
PyObject* iter = PyObject_GetIter(r);

item = PyIter_Next(iter);
int i = 0;
PyObject* iter2 = PyObject_GetIter(item);
PyObject* item2;
while (item2 = PyIter_Next(iter2))
{
    s[i] = PyFloat_AsDouble(item2);
    Py_XDECREF(item2);
    i++;
}
Py_XDECREF(item);

// ! Here you probably intended another call to PyObject_GetIter
item = PyIter_Next(iter);
i = 0;
iter2 = PyObject_GetIter(item);
while (item2 = PyIter_Next(iter2))
{
    b[i] = PyFloat_AsDouble(item2);
    Py_XDECREF(item2);
    i++;
}
Py_XDECREF(item);
```

The crash may however be due to other reasons (it depends on the documented behavior of the functions you're using).

Comment: Thanks a lot,I found the reason.I do this Py_XDECREF(item) three times....but I just have tow lists

Comment: @wtm If your problem is solved by the information someone gives you, make sure you "accept" the answer...that's the etiquette on StackOverflow...

Comment: @wtm Nice all depends on who you ask.  Your question was poorly formed, but I antagonized Mr. Alf (who is quite experienced and from whose answers I regularly learn things) to introduce a balance I think needs to be maintained.  Good cop, bad cop...?  :)